# Caixa de pesquisa em HTML

Tags: html, algoritmo-de-busca, redirecionamento

Gostaria de saber se é possível criar uma caixa de pesquisa em HTML, onde a pessoa vai digitar um texto e será direcionada para uma pesquisa interna no site.
Estou criando um site com o Google Sites (A ideia é ser bem simples, sem muitas funcionalidades e custos).

Acontece que eu quero colocar uma caixa de pesquisa e estou com dificuldade, pois eu preciso que ao pesquisar seja direcionado.
EX:

O site é https://sites.google.com/abc.com.br/meusite
Se a pessoa pesquisar "teste"
Deve ser direcionada para o site https://sites.google.com/search/abc.com.br/mesite?query=teste

Não queria que fosse aberto uma nova aba.

Andei pesquisando, mas não consegui achar nada que ajudasse.

Answer (score -2):

Podemos usar o window.location.href para redirecionar o utilizador para outro URL.

```
<input type="text" id="pesquisa">
<button id="pesquisa-submit">Pesquisar</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#pesquisa-submit").on('click', function() {
        var query = $("#pesquisa").val();
        window.location.href = "https://sites.google.com/search/abc.com.br/mesite?query=" + query;
    });
</script>
```